# Kusto # Change month's name for their number

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

I would like to change the month's name for their number, so Mar-> 3 or Jan-> 1.

Kusto image

[image]

I thought about replacing, but I think that I use a lot of variables...

Do you have any suggestions?

Regards.

Comment: What is your current query?

Comment: It seems you are not giving the whole picture. Please share more information regarding your challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in your Formula Tool to Change month's name to their number:

SWITCH([Month], Null(),

"Jan", "01",
"Feb", "02",
"Mar", "03",
"Apr", "04",
"May", "05",
"Jun", "06",
"Jul", "07",
"Aug", "08",
"Sep", "09",
"Oct", "10",
"Nov", "11",
"Dec", "12"
)

Comment: Hey, did you check this??